# How to overlap two adjacent edges of 2 framed minipages placed side by side?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage, rules

How to overlap the adjacent edges?
In other words, the adjacent edges should be combined into one edge shared between to minipages such that all rules will have the same thickness.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,dvipsnames,dvips,cmyk]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=10mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc,xcolor}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2mm}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm}
\begin{document}\noindent{\color{red}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
\color{blue}\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
\color{blue}\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}}
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

Assume using table is prohibited by the game rule.

Comment: Didn't I advise you not to give answers in questions? Please remove the answer from the question and post it as an answer. And please keep this in mind! `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik, but I want to give Herbert a Green Check mark.

Comment: Doesn't matter; please keep questions questions. Herbert won't mind, I guess. Please have a look [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/535/1235) for more thoughts on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final solution based on Herbert's answer with a bit adjustment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=10mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc,xcolor}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2mm}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm}
\begin{document}\noindent{\color{red}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth-1.5\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
\color{blue}\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth-1.5\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
\color{blue}\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}}
\end{document}
```

This is the final solution based on @Herbert's solution. I made a small correction in his calculation.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=10mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc,xcolor}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2mm}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm}
\begin{document}\noindent{\color{red}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
\color{blue}\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth-\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
\color{blue}\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}}
\end{document}
```

a tabular will do the same ...

Comment: thanks for the solution. But I think you did a small miscalculation for the minipages. The minipages should have a width of `0.5\textwidth-1.5\fboxrule-2\fboxsep` rather than `0.5\textwidth-\fboxrule-2\fboxsep`, right?

Comment: Rather than `0.5\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep` as well.

Comment: depends of what you like to have. I didn't touch the settings of the first minipage, the resaon why I used `0.5\textwidth-\fboxrule-2\fboxsep`

Comment: Sorry. I should move the green check mark to my own answer because of the site rule explained by @Hendrik above.